# Invalid unixTime error when processing GPKG file with ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, geojson, ogr2ogr, geopackage, time

I am looking [at forestry data](https://avoin.metsakeskus.fi/aineistot/Metsankayttoilmoitukset/Maakunta/) of Finland's Etelä-Savo region. I download the data:

```
curl -L -O https://avoin.metsakeskus.fi/aineistot/Metsankayttoilmoitukset/Maakunta/MKI_Etelä-Savo.zip
```

Unzip it:

```
ditto -xk MKI_Etelä-Savo.zip MKI_Etela-Savo/
```

And try converting it to GeoJSON:

```
ogr2ogr out.geojson MKI_Etela-Savo/MKI_Etelä-Savo.gpkg
```

Output I get:

```
ERROR 6: Invalid unixTime = 371054750083200
ERROR 6: Invalid unixTime = 371054750083200
ERROR 6: Invalid unixTime = 371055261657600
ERROR 6: Invalid unixTime = 371055261657600
```

Which is very strange, as `371054750083200` and `371055261657600` seem to be valid unix timestamps, pointing to points in time on 4th October 1981  (can check [here](https://www.epochconverter.com/) or [here](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/)).

A way around this error could be disregarding all columns of type `Date`. One can do that via:

```
nonDateColumns=$(ogrinfo -so -al -json MKI_Etela-Savo/MKI_Etelä-Savo.gpkg forestusedeclaration | jq -r '.layers[].fields[] | select(.type != "Date") | .name' | tr '\n ' ',' | sed 's/,$//')
layerName=$(ogrinfo -json MKI_Etela-Savo/MKI_Etelä-Savo.gpkg | jq -r '.layers[].name')
ogr2ogr no_date_columns.geojson MKI_Etela-Savo/MKI_Etelä-Savo.gpkg -sql "SELECT ${nonDateColumns} FROM ${layerName}"
```

`no_date_columns.geojson` is then successfully created. This way of doing it is just avoiding the problem instead of properly fixing it, so I am not a fan.

**How do I fix the `Invalid unixTime` error?**

Comment: 04-Oct-1981 is just 371 million seconds, not 371 trillion. Multiplying by 1000 for milliseconds makes sense due to the range of 64-bit integers, but multiplying for microseconds makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This SQL query

```
select id, standarrivaldate as d
from forestusedeclaration
order by d asc;
```

Prints these two rows first:

```
58624   1005-11-23
59494   1005-11-23
```

Obviously that date is not correct. There is also another odd date `1022-02-08`. We can't know for sure what are the correct dates but maybe they are a thousand year later. Fixing the data makes the conversion into GeoJSON to work

```
update forestusedeclaration
set standarrivaldate='2005-11-23'
where standarrivaldate='1005-11-23';

update forestusedeclaration
set standarrivaldate='2022-02-08'
where standarrivaldate='1022-02-08';
```

You can use whatever SQLite client for correcting the data. With ogrinfo the syntax is:

```
ogrinfo  MKI_Etelä-Savo.gpkg -sql "update forestusedeclaration set standarrivaldate='2022-02-08'   where standarrivaldate='1022-02-08'"
```

Answer (score 1):

### Loads fine in QGIS

I agree with @user30184, those 'dates' do look bad. Nevertheless, opening the GPKG in QGIS apparently works just fine. It read 130523 tuples.

The dates QGIS reads for the id's mentioned:

```
id      standarivaldate
58624   2013-06-07
59494   2014-01-15
```

The GEOJSON export also looks fine regarding dates and times.

Not much help if you want to automate your process, but if you just need the data this may be a reasonable workaround.

Comment: Thanks for checking! This is very strange, as my QGIS does display the problematic dates.

Comment: You're welcome, but I'm out of my depth here. I'm on QGIS 3.16.5. Let me know if you need more info or testing.  I guess this sounds like a bug?